# Why do I get a lifetime error when I store closure as a variable and no error when I declare it as an expression?

Tags: rust, aws-lambda, closures

I'm using the AWS Lambda (via the [lambda_http](https://crates.io/crates/lambda_http) crate) and the following code doesn't compile:

```rust
let handler = service_fn(move |event: Request| async  {
    handler_organization_post(&shared_client, event).await
});
lambda_http::run(handler).await
```

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
   --> organization/organization_post/src/main.rs:125:52
    |
125 |       let handler = service_fn(move |event: Request| async  {
    |  ______________________________---------------------_^
    | |                              |                   |
    | |                              |                   return type of closure `[async block@organization/organization_post/src/main.rs:125:52: 127:6]` contains a lifetime `'2`
    | |                              lifetime `'1` represents this closure's body
126 | |         handler_organization_post(&shared_client, event).await
127 | |     });
    | |_____^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
    |
    = note: closure implements `Fn`, so references to captured variables can't escape the closure
```

However, if I simply inline the closure declaration into the call to `lambda_http::run`, the program compiles and runs with no problems:

```rust
lambda_http::run(service_fn(move |event: Request| async move {
    handler_organization_post(&shared_client, event).await
})).await
```

In my head, these are semantically equivalent, so what's going on? I'm clearly missing something and would appreciate a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: Where is shared_client defined?

Comment: You have an extra `move` in `async move` vs just `async` when you inline the closure.

Comment: @MarkSaving `shared_client` is just a ref to a dynamodb client struct and is defined just above the code listed as `let shared_client = &client;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `async move` for the closure to be valid. This is the difference between the two versions of your code - the second uses `async move`, while the first does not.

To understand this, recall that an `async` block evaluates to an `impl Future` - to some value which implements the `Future` trait. The code inside the block is not immediately executed. It is only executed when the future is “polled” - that is, when someone tries to evaluate the future and get the underlying value.

Consider a very simple closure using `async`.

```rust
let closure = |y: i32| async { y + 1 };
```

This is actually not a valid closure. The `async` block does not have the `move` keyword, so the future it evaluates to contains a reference to `y`, not `y` itself. By the time the `async` block is evaluated, this reference will no longer be valid, since the closure will have returned. To make everything work, you need to change the code to

```rust
let closure = |y: i32| async move { y + 1 };
```

Comment: OMG I got so tunnel visioned on the variable that I completely missed the second move statement. Thanks!